# Executing sed via execvp makes other pipes blocked

Tags: pipe, fork, stdin, execvp, dup2

I am playing around with `fork/pipe/dup/execvp` concepts and came out with a little problem:

I made a test main to execute sort and manually send some numbers via pipe bound to STDIN and it works as expected: When I close the stdin writer, I can read the sorted numbers output.

However, if I also start sed (or other program which listens on STDIN) in the same way with his own pair of pipes (not connected to the ones used in sort), then I got a block on read from sort's pipe that is gone if I just comment the sed execution part.

The idea is to be able to read from "first" one and have the others waiting for command sending.

So the questions are:
a) Do they share the same STDIN so then when sed starts it counts as a possible writter and this is why read blocks?
and
b) How then I can spawn those N process **from the same parent** that make their STDIN undependant from each other?

This is the test code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <wait.h>

int sed_pipe_in[2], sed_pipe_out[2], sort_pipe_in[2], sort_pipe_out[2];

pid_t execute_sort() {
    pid_t sort = fork();

    if (sort == 0) {
        close(sort_pipe_in[1]);
        dup2(sort_pipe_in[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        close(sort_pipe_in[0]);

        close(sort_pipe_out[0]);
        dup2(sort_pipe_out[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(sort_pipe_out[1]);

        char* args[] = { "sort", "-", NULL };
        execvp("/usr/bin/sort", args);
        std::cerr << "Execvp failed!" << std::endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
    else if (sort == -1) {
        std::cerr << "Fork failed!" << std::endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
    else {
        close(sort_pipe_in[0]);
        close(sort_pipe_out[1]);
    }
    return sort;
}

pid_t execute_sed() {
    pid_t sed = fork();

    if (sed == 0) {
        close(sed_pipe_in[1]);
        dup2(sed_pipe_in[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        close(sed_pipe_in[0]);

        close(sed_pipe_out[0]);
        dup2(sed_pipe_out[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(sed_pipe_out[1]);

        char* args[] = { "sed", "-e", "s/3/9/", NULL };
        execvp("/bin/sed", args);
        std::cerr << "Execvp failed!" << std::endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
    else if (sed == -1) {
        std::cerr << "Fork failed!" << std::endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
    else {
        close(sed_pipe_in[0]);
        close(sed_pipe_out[1]);
    }
    return sed;
}

int main() {
    pipe(sed_pipe_in);
    pipe(sed_pipe_out);
    pipe(sort_pipe_in);
    pipe(sort_pipe_out);

    pid_t sort = execute_sort();
    // Why removing the following line makes the program to work
    // if sed is not yet connected to sort?
    pid_t sed = execute_sed();
    
    
    // Only parent will get here
    // Sending input to sort
    write(sort_pipe_in[1], "3\n2\n1\n", 7);
    close(sort_pipe_in[1]);

    char buffer[500];
    // If sed is started then this read is blocking
    ssize_t bytes = read(sort_pipe_out[0], buffer, 500);
    std::string output(buffer, bytes);

    std::cout << "Output is " << output << std::endl;

    // Sort will exit here as stdin is closed
    int status;
    waitpid(sort, &status, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

If `execute_sed` is commented out, then the output is correct:

```
1
2
3
```

but if `execute_sed` is not commented then the process is blocked at read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each of your `sort` and `sed` forks, the other fork is keeping file descriptors for the other's process's pipes open (as forked children inherit file descriptors).

Since `sort`'s `STDIN` is still open (and held by the `sed` process), it continues waiting for input.

You can either just have each one `close()` the unneeded file descriptors, create the pipes using `pipe2(res_pipe, O_CLOEXEC)` (which will make them close automatically on `exec*`), or use `fcntl` with `F_GETFD`/`F_SETFD` to mark the pipe file descriptors with `FD_CLOEXEC` for the same result.

Comment: Oh my god... since this minimal example came from other more complicated code I totally missed this possibility! Thanks a lot!